# Tensorflow Object-Detection API - Hyperparameter Tuning & Grid Search

Tags: tensorflow, object-detection, object-detection-api, hyperparameters

I am currently working with the Tensorflow Object-Detection API and I want to fine-tune a pre-trained model. Therefore, a hyperparameter-tuning is required.

Does the API already provide some kind of hyperparameter-tuning (like a grid search)? If there is nothing available, how can I implement a simple grid search to tune (the most relevant) hyperparameters?

Furthermore, does the API provide some kind of Early Stopping function that automatically aborts the training process if the accuracy does not change anymore.

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: thanks a lot! However, I am not sure if we are on the same page. Grid search does not imply a new parameter, or what do you mean by new parameter? Nevertheless, I can find a good configuration by hand. I am more interested in Early Stopping. Does the API provide some code for this? I expect a function or something like that which automatically stops when the training loss does not change significantly over, let's say 100 iterations. Do you have an idea?

Comment: @danyfang thanks. I tried to run the function, however, an error occurs in line 137 that refers obviously to line 681in model_lib.py. Two arguments are missing for the function. 

Steps to reproduce: I copied the function in the /models/research/object_detection  folder, renamed it and executed it in the same way the provided model_main function by the API. Any steps I forget? Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: Adding the missing variables (```train_input_fn``` and ```train_steps```) only leads to another error in line 158. ``` TypeError: eval_spec must have type tf.estimator.EvalSpec. Got: <class tensorflow.python.estimator.training.TrainSpec> ```  Am I doing something completely wrong?

Comment: Added the missing parameters (even when they are unused to create the EvalSpec), now it is running. However, it is very slow compared to the model_main.py provided by TF OD. Do not know what is the reason for this behavior, accuracy is also slowier compared to the the "original" function after the same amount of time.