# Tensorflow Object-Detection API - Early Stopping

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, object-detection, object-detection-api

I work with the TF OD API and I want to use the early stop function within the offical repo.

I found a custom code snippet (https://github.com/hongym7/early_stopping/blob/master/model_main.py) and I found another issue on Stackoverflow related to the same topic ([Tensorflow Object-Detection API - Hyperparameter Tuning & Grid Search](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56116229/tensorflow-object-detection-api-hyperparameter-tuning-grid-search)). However, it seems like there is something missing.

I have the same issue. I want to use the early stop function provided by Hong (see first link) but it does not work for me as well. Does anybody has a clue what is wrong? I did the same as described in scope of the Stackoverflow issue.

Or is there a more convinient way how to implement a simple version of early stop that aborts training if no changes are detected anymore?

Thanks

Comment: I would recommend saying exactly what went wrong, what code you are trying to run (copy/paste here), and give the errors you are receiving, etc.. Early stopping would be a nice built-in for an ML api.